# Character encoding garbled characters in post JSF

Tags: html, jsf, character-encoding

I have the following document being posted in JSF.

```
<h:panelGrid columns="2">
                <h:outputText value="Klubbnamn"></h:outputText>
                <h:inputText name="clubname" value="#{club.name}"></h:inputText>
            </h:panelGrid>
            <h:commandButton value="Spara" action="#{serviceHCP.saveClub(club) }"></h:commandButton>
```

writing åäö as the value for posting will render me Ã¥Ã¤Ã¶ back. Everything written in the xhtml file will look like it should it's only the posted value that will be garbled. If I hard code it in the java class it will be correctly saved in the database. So I am sure there is something wrong with the post.

I have tried switching the webpage to is0-8859-1 without result. Tomcat is reporting default as utf-8.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/BowlingFacelets/faces/javax.faces.resource/theme.css?ln=primefaces-aristo" />
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Default title</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="hcp-style.css" /></head>

<body>

.....

<td>ID</td>
<td>klubb</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>Ã¥Ã¤Ã¶</td>
 ....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This definitely looks like a problem with the request encoding. You should check the request character encoding header of the HTTP POST with [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com) or a tool like [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org).

In the request headers look for the `Content-Type`. It must contain: `charset=utf-8`

If this is not the case something in your setup is wrong because JSF should take care of the request character encoding.

Despite you can try to set the character encoding in a self-made filter. It could be something like this:

```
    @WebFilter("/*")
    public class CharEncodingFilter implements Filter {

        @Override
        public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
            FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {
            request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
    }
```

**See also:**

- [Unicode - How to get characters right?](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html)

**Similar questions:**

- [character encoding UTF-8 in JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17628354/character-encoding-utf-8-in-jsf)
- [JSF 2.0 request.getParameter return a string with wrong encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3897301/jsf-2-0-request-getparameter-return-a-string-with-wrong-encoding)
- [POST parameters using wrong encoding in JSF 1.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8609994/post-parameters-using-wrong-encoding-in-jsf-1-2)

Comment: Just for someone who has trouble like me with the "@WebFilter cannot be resolved" can check here: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api/3.0.1