# Displaying a JSF requestLink parameter containing a + sign

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-1.2

Strange one this. I have a  tag in my JSF page which contains a parameter that contains a + sign. When the resulting hyperlink is clicked the URL converts the + sign to a space, as this is how spaces in URLs are represented.

Is there any way of encoding this parameter to display "%2b" (which is the urlencoded string) instead of +? I am using JSF 1.2

```xml
<hx:requestLink styleClass="requestLink" id="link31"
    action="#{sellingMarginBean.changeView}">
    <h:outputText styleClass="outputText" id="text81"
        value="#{varsummaryDataList.tier.description}"></h:outputText>  
    <f:param
        value="#{varsummaryDataList.tier.tierCode}"
        name="tierCode" id="param51"></f:param>
</hx:requestLink>
```

If I change the value of tierCode to replace any '+' with '%2b' before putting out to the screen this works, but it's a hack at best as it means creating a custom method on my Tier domain object or cycling through summaryDataList and performing the replace.

Thanks in advance

Steve

Comment: Could you post your code? What happens if you directly replace your plus signs by a `%2b` before the JSF evaluation happens?

Comment: Just edited the post :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this post](http://balusc.blogspot.com.es/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html) by BalusC:

> JSP/Servlet request: during request processing an average application server will by default use the ISO 8859-1 character encoding to URL-decode the request parameters. You need to force the character encoding to UTF-8 yourself. First this: "URL encoding" must not to be confused with "character encoding". URL encoding is merely a conversion of characters to their numeral representations in the %xx format, so that special characters can be passed through URL without any problems. The client will URL-encode the characters before sending them to the server. The server should URL-decode the characters using the same character encoding.

So probably your client and server are not using the same URL(URI)-encoding. Your best bet is to force the server itself to use UTF-8 encoding. That depends on what server you're using.

You could also use JSTL's [`fn:replace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fn/replace.fn.html) for your parameter, as an alternative but more "hacky" solution. Remember to define the JSTL taglib in your namespace set (`xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"`).

```xml
<f:param
    value="#{fn:replace(varsummaryDataList.tier.tierCode, '+', '%2b'}"
    name="tierCode" id="param51" />
```

**See also:**

- [POST parameters using wrong encoding in JSF 1.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8609994/post-parameters-using-wrong-encoding-in-jsf-1-2)
- [JSF 2.0 request.getParameter return a string with wrong encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3897301/jsf-2-0-request-getparameter-return-a-string-with-wrong-encoding)
- [How can I manipulate a String in a JSF tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7901875/how-can-i-manipulate-a-string-in-a-jsf-tag)

Comment: Are + signs encoded differently though? They're basic ASCII.

Comment: @EvanKnowles, in fact, there are, but they remain in conflict with HTTP request keywords. That's why they should be encoded in a different way.